# Is it possible to use Record Fields as URL params in HTTP Client Processor in StreamSets?

Tags: streamsets

I'm new to StreamSets, thanks in advance for any help.

In my pipeline records (JSON) I have a field with Geo-coordinates (lat, lon) and I'm trying to add more meta-data to them. I'm wondering if it's possible to use a HTTP Client Processor to realize the operation described here https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/ using the lat, lon values of my records. If it is, could you point me for some documentation or article that describes how to do it?

I've been able to use HTTP Client as Origins in other occasions, but i can't figure out how to use the values in the URL.

For example if the values of my record were

```
{
            "lat": 41.195519,
            "lon":-8.666526,
            "format": "jsonv2"
}
```

The url should look like: 
`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=41.226599&lon=-8.709737`

Answer (score 2):

Figured out, simply GET to

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=${record:value('/format')}&lat=${record:value('/lat')}&lon=${record:value('/lon')}
```